# Mysql query returns all rows. Why?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS o . * , titles.title AS title, categories.category AS category,

images.image AS image, urls.url AS url, descriptions.description AS description,

from_sites.from_site AS from_site, prices.price AS price

FROM oglasi AS o

LEFT JOIN titles ON o.title_id = titles.title_id

LEFT JOIN categories ON o.category_id = categories.category_id

LEFT JOIN images ON o.image_id = images.image_id

LEFT JOIN urls ON o.url_id = urls.url_id

LEFT JOIN descriptions ON o.description_id = descriptions.description_id

LEFT JOIN from_sites ON o.from_site_id = from_sites.from_site_id

LEFT JOIN prices ON o.price_id = prices.price_id

WHERE categories.category_id = "28"

OR categories.category_id = "29"

OR categories.category_id = "30"

OR categories.category_id = "31"

OR categories.category_id = "32"

OR categories.category_id = "33"

OR categories.category_id = "34"

OR categories.category_id = "35"

AND from_sites.from_site_id =7

ORDER BY o.izdvojen, titles.title ASC
```

The only problem here is that AND from_sites.from_site_id=7 is ignored. So it list's all of the subcats from all of sites.
But when i try this same query only with one category_id and the from_site_id , then it works how it's supposed.

Can please someone tell me what's wrong here ?

Comment: Why is category_id not simply an integer?

Comment: You can change `ON o.title_id = titles.title_id` to `USING (id)` and your query will be much easier to read.

Comment: All the other joins can be simplified in this way also...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis to explicitly tell MySQL which clauses to calculate first.

Try this:

```
WHERE (categories.category_id = "28"
OR categories.category_id = "29"
OR categories.category_id = "30"
OR categories.category_id = "31"
OR categories.category_id = "32"
OR categories.category_id = "33"
OR categories.category_id = "34"
OR categories.category_id = "35")
AND from_sites.from_site_id =7
```

Or something similar if that wasn't exactly what you meant.

Comment: +1 `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` see [11.3.1. Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try using parentheses to dictate how the logical operations are evaluated.

If you want something that is in any of the listed categories and in addition to that, is from_site_id = 7, then your where section should look like this:

```
WHERE (
      categories.category_id = "28"
      OR categories.category_id = "29"
      OR categories.category_id = "30"
      OR categories.category_id = "31"
      OR categories.category_id = "32"
      OR categories.category_id = "33"
      OR categories.category_id = "34"
      OR categories.category_id = "35"
      )
      AND from_sites.from_site_id =7
```

Your current query is saying to return all rows where category_id = 28-34 OR is from category 35 and is fromSiteID = 7 (so the fromSiteID condition is ignored for all but categoryID 35).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff you don't seem to need in the original query.  May I suggest a simplified version?

```
SELECT title, category, image, url, description, from_site, price
FROM oglasi
LEFT JOIN titles USING (title_id)
LEFT JOIN categories USING (category_id)
LEFT JOIN images USING (image_id)
LEFT JOIN urls USING (url_id)
LEFT JOIN descriptions USING (description_id)
LEFT JOIN from_sites USING (from_site_id)
LEFT JOIN prices USING (price_id)
WHERE category_id IN (28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35) AND from_site_id =7
ORDER BY izdvojen, title
```

Comment: thank you,this is doing the same thing lol. I recently started working with more 'complex' queries,so i'm still learning it.